# How to remove <li></li> from ul?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to remove a particular `<li></li>` from the ul list?
i am adding it dynamically...
and i need to remove it when the user click on clear. how can i do that?

Comment: do you want to remove the text within that `<li></li>` too?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That depends on what you have and what you're adding. Assuming you end up added items so it looks like this:

```
<ul id="list">
  <li><a href="#" class="clear">clear</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="clear">clear</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="clear">clear</a></li>
</ul>
```

then use [`remove()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/remove#expr) to remove a single item:

```
$("#list a.clear").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
  return false;
});
```

but if you have:

```
<ul id="list">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
<a href-"#" id="clear">Clear</a>
```

and you want to clear all of them then use [`empty()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/empty):

```
$("#clear").click(function() {
  $("#list").empty();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: I have a dynamically created list (<li> s) under <ul> (which is define in html itself). Can I remove a specific <li> from that? As in your second example, lets assume <li> tags inside <ul> are created dynamically. Can I remove <li>Two</li> only ?

Answer (score 3):

```
$('li').remove();
```

Will remove all the li elements... I suggest you give it an `id` attribute when you add it so that you know which one you'll want to remove, then select it specifically with:

```
$('#my_li').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Put a unique value into the elements id attribute when you write it.  You then have a known unique referrence point from which to target that element for later manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var ul = document.getElementById("yourElementId");

 while (ul.firstChild)
     ul.removeChild(ul.firstChild);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for deleting all lis:

```
$("#Your_ul_Id").children().remove()
```

Use eq(index_of_your_li) for deleting a li:

```
$("#Your_ul_Id:eq(1)").remove()
```

Use .not("#Your_li_Id") for deleting all lis except one:

```
$("#Your_ul_Id").children().not("#Your_li_Id").remove()
```